# align - how to push equations to the left?

Tags: align

How do I clean up my equations below? I would like the text "object motion probability" to not exceed the margin and the second line to be pushed to the left. This is how it looks like currently

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[twocolumn,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{align}
    \sum_{s,i,j,t} \lambda_1(\underbrace{||\hat{y}^t_\Psi - y^t||_2^2}_\text{human pose} + \underbrace{||\hat{x}_{\varphi,i}^t - x_i^t||_2^2}_\text{object pose}) + \lambda_2\underbrace{\hat{\alpha}^t_i \log \alpha^t_i}_{\mathclap{\text{object motion probability}}} \nonumber \\ + \lambda_1\underbrace{\delta_s^t||(\hat{y}^t_{\Phi,s} - y^t){\circ} (1-m_s)||_2^2}_\text{refined arms} + \lambda_2\underbrace{\hat{\beta}^t_{s,j} \log \hat{\beta}^t_{s,j}}_{\mathclap{\text{contact probability}}} \nonumber
\end{align}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Please all instances of `||` with `\Vert`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fleqn` environment of the `nccmath` package in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[twocolumn,margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools,nccmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{multline*}
    \sum_{s,i,j,t} \lambda_1(\underbrace{\lVert\hat{y}^t_\Psi - y^t\rVert_2^2}_\text{human pose} + \underbrace{\lVert\hat{x}_{\varphi,i}^t - x_i^t\rVert_2^2}_\text{object pose}) 
     + \lambda_2\underbrace{\hat{\alpha}^t_i \log \alpha^t_i}_{\mathclap{\text{object motion probability}}}\\
    + \lambda_1\underbrace{\delta_s^t\lVert(\hat{y}^t_{\Phi,s} - y^t)\circ (1-m_s)\rVert_2^2}_\text{refined arms} 
     + \lambda_2\underbrace{\hat{\beta}^t_{s,j} \log \hat{\beta}^t_{s,j}}_{\mathclap{\text{contact probability}}}
\end{multline*}
\end{fleqn}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The expression as written (just) fits if you set `\mathindent` to zero.

Note `\lVert` not`||`, you can use a `*` environment rather than `\nonumber` every line, and use `_{\text{...}}` not `_\text{...}` (the latter works by accident but is really weird and vastly complicates conversion of the expression to html or other formats.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[twocolumn,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength\mathindent{0pt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{multline*}
    \sum_{s,i,j,t} \lambda_1(\underbrace{\lVert\hat{y}^t_\Psi - 
      y^t\rVert_2^2}_{\text{human pose}} + \underbrace{\lVert\hat{x}_{\varphi,i}^t - 
         x_i^t\rVert_2^2}_{\text{object pose}}) + 
        \lambda_2\underbrace{\hat{\alpha}^t_i \log \alpha^t_i}_{\mathclap{\text{object motion probability}}} r \\
 + \lambda_1\underbrace{\delta_s^t\lVert(\hat{y}^t_{\Phi,s} - y^t){\circ} (1-m_s)\rVert_2^2}_\text{refined arms} + 
\lambda_2\underbrace{\hat{\beta}^t_{s,j} \log \hat{\beta}^t_{s,j}}_{\mathclap{\text{contact probability}}}
\end{multline*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about you split the equation at a sum symbol and keep each sub expression in separate line?

I would also suggest a small change inside each `\underbrace`. If you insert struts, you stretch contents vertically and push each annotation to the same level. The macro `\xmathstrut` (`mathtools`) has a parameter `size` that corresponds to height of a strut.

If you want subscript in multiple lines, try `\substack`. Its variant `subarray` (environment) can also control alignment. Since annotations are typeset in math (italics), you need to use `\text{}` in each row. This can be automated using `\cellcollect` and `\endcellcollect` (`cellcoll`) in the regular `array`.

Here's the code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[twocolumn,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand\textcell[1]{\text{\scriptsize#1}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{xsubarray}{mb}{%
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.65}%
  \begin{tabular}{>{\collectcell\textcell}#1<{\endcollectcell}}#2\end{tabular}}{}
\newcommand\xxstrut[1][0.5]{\xmathstrut{#1}}


\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    \sum_{s,i,j,t} \mathrlap{\lambda_1 \Bigl(
    \underbrace{\xxstrut
    \lVert\hat{y}^t_\Psi - y^t\rVert_2^2}_{\text{human pose}}
    {}+{}
    \underbrace{\xxstrut
    \lVert\hat{x}_{\varphi,i}^t - x_i^t\rVert_2^2}_\text{object pose}
    \Bigr)} & \\
            & + \lambda_2 \Bigl(
              \underbrace{\xxstrut
              \hat{\alpha}^t_i \log \alpha^t_i}_{\mathclap{
              \begin{xsubarray}{c}object motion\\probability\end{xsubarray}}}
              {}+{}
              \underbrace{\xxstrut
              \hat{\beta}^t_{s,j} \log \hat{\beta}^t_{s,j}}_{\mathclap{
              \begin{xsubarray}{c}contact\vphantom{bj}\\probability\end{xsubarray}}}
              \Bigr) \\
            & + \lambda_1 \Bigl(
              \underbrace{\xxstrut
              \delta_s^t\lVert(\hat{y}^t_{\Phi,s} - y^t){\circ} (1-m_s)\rVert_2^2}_\text{refined arms}
              \Bigr).
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `\substack` directive to introduce a line break in the second argument of the `\underbrace` directive in question. Next, since there's no natural alignment point in the two rows, I'd use a `multline` environment instead of an `align` environment. Finally, do take care to assure that the text arguments of the `\underbrace` instructions in line 1 line up vertically.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[twocolumn,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% define a '\norm' macro:
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert
% define a typographic strut with height and depth of '\hat{x}^t_{\varphi,i}' 
\newcommand\mystrut{\vphantom{\hat{x}^t_{\varphi,i}}} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] % filler text
\begin{multline*}
    \sum_{s,i,j,t} \lambda_1 \bigl(
    \underbrace{\norm{\hat{y}^t_\Psi - y^t}_2^2\mystrut}_{\text{human pose}}
    + \underbrace{\norm{\hat{x}_{\varphi,i}^t - x_i^t}_2^2}_{\text{object pose}}
    \bigr) 
    + \lambda_2\underbrace{\hat{\alpha}^t_i \log \alpha^t_i\mystrut}_{\mathclap{\substack{\text{object motion}\\ \text{probability}}}}  \\
    + \lambda_1\underbrace{\delta_s^t \norm{(\hat{y}^t_{\Phi,s} - y^t){\circ} (1-m_s)}_2^2}_{\text{refined arms}}
    + \lambda_2\underbrace{\hat{\beta}^t_{s,j} \log \hat{\beta}^t_{s,j}}_{\mathclap{\text{contact probability}}}
\end{multline*}
\lipsum[2] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, but is it possible to do something like \hspace{-1cm} ? I tried inserting it and it did nothing. I would very much prefer to utilize the horizontal space instead of using up more vertical space.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account the width of the text that goes beyond the underbrace and that you make zero with `\mathclap`.

You can also (locally) remove the `\multlinegap`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[twocolumn,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\ubrace}[2]{{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begingroup\setlength{\multlinegap}{0pt}
\begin{multline*}
  \sum_{s,i,j,t}
    \lambda_{1}\bigl(\,\ubrace{\|\hat{y}^t_\Psi - y^t\|_2^2\vphantom{^{}_{j}}}
                              {\text{human pose}}
   +\ubrace{\|\hat{x}_{\varphi,i}^t - x_i^t\|_2^2}{\text{object pose}}\,\bigr)
   +\lambda_2\ubrace{\hat{\alpha}^t_i \log \alpha^t_i\vphantom{^{}_{\phi}}}
                    {\mathclap{\text{object motion probability}}}
   \hphantom{\scriptstyle\mathrm{bability}}
\\
   +\lambda_1\ubrace{\delta_s^t\|(\hat{y}^t_{\Phi,s}-y^t)\circ(1-m_s)\|_2^2\vphantom{^{}_{j}}}
                    {\text{refined arms}}
   +\lambda_2\ubrace{\hat{\beta}^t_{s,j} \log \hat{\beta}^t_{s,j}}
                    {\mathclap{\text{contact probability}}}
\hphantom{\scriptstyle\mathrm{ity}}
\end{multline*}
\endgroup
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

Note the phantoms to get the same level of the underbraces and the `\ubrace` command; you can clearly see that the spacing of the + signs is wrong with `\underbrace`. Note also `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`, together with the thin space to avoid clashes.

[image]